# Will static methods decrease my overhead?

Tags: c++, memory-management, static

Does a class have to allocate memory for its non-static member functions every time a new instance is created?

To put a finer point on it, if I were writing a class `v3d` representing 3-space vectors, would I use less memory by defining

`static v3d::dotProduct(v3d v1, v3d v2)`

as opposed to

`v3d::dotProduct(v3d v2)` ?

Comment: Nope, in both cases you still have two `v3d` objects alive. Worry about sensible _semantics_ first, then profile.

Comment: Additionally, it is usually preferable that you make something like this a free function, rather than a method in your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither static nor non-static member functions are stored per instance. In the case of non-static member functions, the way I understand it is that they are translated into something like (probably less readable than this):

```
v3d_dotProduct(v3d this, v3d v2)
```

And the calls to them are translated accordingly. If you want to improve performance, I would recommend using inline functions as these essentially copy the function contents to the place that you call it. I don't think this will decrease your memory usage, but it's worth using for class functions (static and non-static) which are called many times per second.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/20600/

Comment: 1: A developer has very little control of whether a method/function is inlined. The keyword 'inline' has no affect (in normal situations) on whether the compiler decides to inline a method. This is because programmers are notoriously bad at making this decision correctly (and practically always wrong) and thus compiler writers decided it was better to ignore this request and make the decision automatically in the compiler. It is usually considered bad practice to use (unless it is requires). It is only required for linking purposes when a function is defined outside the class but in a header.

Comment: 2: Neither static nor member methods are stored per instance (contrary to what your answer seems to imply).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Edited my post to clarify on that.

Answer (score 2):

There is one instance of the function in memory.  It has nothing to do with static or not. You don't allocate memory for member functions.

Or maybe I misunderstood. Perhaps you meant the function somehow takes up space in the object?  No, it doesn't.  At the object code level, membership is essentially just a name convention and a hidden 'this' parameter.  If virtual, there is typically a single vtable, the same one for all instances.

However, in your examples, you appear to be passing all the v3d objects by value. This means in the static case you're making 2 object copies (one for each arg) and in the non-static case you're making only 1 object copy.

If you passed the args by reference, you could avoid making copies - except as may be required by the dot-product algorithm, whatever that is (a long time since I did any mathematics).

Comment: But beware! Making a copy of the arguments is not always less efficient. If the object is small, the copy constructor is mostly trivial, and the argument is used a lot, it may be better passed by-copy than by-reference. As usual in these cases, a profile is needed to be sure.

Comment: @rodrigo: The compiler can also make that optimization. If you pass by const reference the compiler can make the decision to pass it as a copy of the original (if it decides that is more efficient). Thus it is best to write the code to make the semantics clear and let the compiler make the decisions about micro optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

In either case the function's code only has a single copy in code memory.  Static functions use the same amount of code memory but use less stack memory because when they are called one less argument is passed on the stack.  Non-static class member functions have an additional argument (the this pointer) that is added to the stack when called.  If you don't use anything in the object that would necessitate using the "this" pointer, you should declare the function static.

The amount of stack memory you will save is likely trivial.  But if the function is called millions of times per second a static function *could* see an improvement in speed due to not having to pass an additional argument on the stack.